# Define Stringformat for tabs?

Tags: java, string, tabs, string-formatting

I have a little bug to fix. You can see in the Picture 3 Months outputted.

[image: That is the result what I get]

So that is my code how I display this result. I tried String.format but I don't know how to use it at this tabs. I tried it with these tabs but unfortunately I found out that the format for the first Month (January) is shorter than the other months. All months use 3 tabs but not the first one.

```
public LinkedList<String> buildMonth(int month) {
    int lengthOfMonth = calender.getLengthOfMonth(this.year, month);
    LinkedList<String> monthList = new LinkedList<>();
    monthList.add(String.format("%-10s",monthname[month]) + String.format("%-17s", this.year));

    for (int day = 1; day <= lengthOfMonth; day++) {
        int daynumber = kf.daynumber(day, month, this.year);
        int weekday = kf.weekday_in_year(this.year, daynumber);
    //weekday give me a number where I can find out which weekname
        
            String monthPlan = weekdayShort[weekday] + "|" + String.format("%02d",day) +"|\t\t\t|" +String.format("%-10s",calender.getTwoDigit(daynumber));
            monthList.add(monthPlan);
        

    }
    return monthList;
}
```

I hope anyone can help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can you please display your code little bit more ? because as per seeing this 1-line, all looks good.

Comment: My actually question was how I can make a String.format() of \t\t\t because I heard that this is not very precise. I can send you the code private because of my teacher if you want