# String.format() doesnt format the output correct

Tags: java, linked-list, formatting, string.format

I have a problem my output is not correct as I want and I dont know how to fix it.

In this picture you can see that the header Januar 2017 . . . . Postponed after a while.

```
Januar 2017            Februar 2017            Maerz 2017            
So|01|            |1    Mi|01|            |32    Mi|01|            |60    
Mo|02|            |2    Do|02|            |33    Do|02|            |61    
Di|03|            |3    Fr|03|            |34    Fr|03|            |62    
Mi|04|            |4    Sa|04|            |35    Sa|04|            |63    
Do|05|            |5    So|05|            |36    So|05|            |64    
Fr|06|            |6    Mo|06|            |37    Mo|06|            |65
```

I am trying to do this. The monthname should start at the point of the Weekdayname(short) So Mo Di Mi Do Fr Su

```
Januar 2017             Februar 2017             Maerz 2017            
So|01|            |1    Mi|01|            |32    Mi|01|            |60    
Mo|02|            |2    Do|02|            |33    Do|02|            |61    
Di|03|            |3    Fr|03|            |34    Fr|03|            |62    
Mi|04|            |4    Sa|04|            |35    Sa|04|            |63    
Do|05|            |5    So|05|            |36    So|05|            |64    
Fr|06|            |6    Mo|06|            |37    Mo|06|            |65
```

That is my code how I build the monthPaper

```
public LinkedList<String> buildMonth(int month) {
    int lengthOfMonth = calender.getLengthOfMonth(this.year, month);
    LinkedList<String> monthList = new LinkedList<>();
    monthList.add(String.format("%-10s",monthname[month]) + String.format("%-17s", this.year));

    for (int day = 1; day <= lengthOfMonth; day++) {
        int daynumber = kf.daynumber(day, month, this.year);
        int weekday = kf.wochentag_im_jahr(this.year, daynumber);


            String monthPlan = weekdayShort[weekday] + "|" + String.format("%02d",day) +"|\t\t\t|" +String.format("%-10s",calender.getTwoDigit(daynumber));
            monthList.add(monthPlan);


    }
    return monthList;
}
```

Comment: #1: I don't know what you mean by "The header Januar ... Postponed after a while."  Maybe "postponed" is the wrong word?  I need clearer details about what's wrong.  It might help if you post what you want the output to look like, as an example (and _not_ as an image), along with the actual output (_not_ as an image), so we can see just what the problem is.  #2: We prefer that example output be included in the question as text, not as an image, wherever possible.  In this case, I had to zoom the image up to 250% and I still had trouble reading it.

Comment: Read [mcve]. And yes, screen shots are discouraged.

Comment: sry i dont know that it scales so much the picture

Comment: @ManuellsenDeve, looks like this question already been asked by you only. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476433/define-stringformat-for-tabs

Comment: I get banned. I try to figure out how to solve that problem vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the length of `/t` can vary in different systems and you should change the format of days' strings. Try to do it in this way

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s|%02d|%20s%-6s", weekdayShort[weekday], day, "|", calender.getTwoDigit(daynumber)));
```

Comment: It works and it has the same width. But the header is not in proper line. I try out

Comment: Ok it worked thank you Yuri. The Problem was by the tabs.